# libGDX: How to read and display text from a .txt file line by line after pressing a key?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make a Visual Novel type of game.
What I'm trying to do is display text from a text file line by line by pressing a space button, like in a usual novel. 
I've overlooked different methods but nothing works out for me. I know there are Scanner and BufferedReader, but are they suitable for what I'm doing?
Right now all that happens is when I press "space" the whole text appears on the screen, and when I let go, it dissapears.

This is my game class:

```
public class NovelGame extends Game {

public static final int WIDTH = 1366;
public static final int HEIGHT = 768;

public SpriteBatch batch;
public String txtFileString;
public String lines[];
public BitmapFont bitmapFont;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    bitmapFont = new BitmapFont();
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    txtFileString = Gdx.files.internal("script.txt").readString();
    String[] anArray = txtFileString.split("\\r?\\n");}



@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();
}}
```

This is my game screen class:

```
public class MainGameScreen implements Screen{

    private Texture img;

    NovelGame game;

    public MainGameScreen (NovelGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        img = new Texture("bck.jpg");

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
        game.bitmapFont.draw(game.batch, game.txtFileString,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
        }
        game.batch.end();

    }
```

I had an idea to display it using while and if, but can't exactly figure out how to do it.

EDIT: I found a way to display text, but now, once I run my game, it starts piling one on another endlessly after I press space.

Code:

```
public class MainGameScreen implements Screen{

private Texture img;    
NovelGame game;

public MainGameScreen (NovelGame game) {
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    img = new Texture("bck.jpg");


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hydra\\Documents\\JAVA_PROJECTS\\gamespace\\core\\assets\\startd.txt")); 

        while((game.strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            game.list.add(game.strLine);
     }
        br.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
        game.showText = true;
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(img, 0, 0);


             if(game.showText) {
                 for(int i = 0; i < game.list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(game.list.get(i));    
                game.bitmapFont.draw(game.batch, game.list.get(i), 100, 50);
             }
            }

    game.batch.end();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here. `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed` returns `true` if only key is pressing currently.

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
    game.bitmapFont.draw(game.batch, game.txtFileString,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
}
```

To fix this add a boolean flag activate it after key is only just pressed:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
    showText = true;
}
```

And in render method:

```
if (showText) {
   game.bitmapFont.draw(game.batch, game.txtFileString,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Now the text stays there, even though it's endlessly looping still.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong in the end. I put everything in render method, and that's why file was being read endlessly. I need to do it only once in the constructor class and then put it in the render method.